# ObservableCollection or DataSet in filling ListView in wpf?

Tags: wpf

Can one one please suggest me which one will be the best, fast and efficient method to fill a `ListView` in a WPF app.

From `ObservableCollection` or from `DataSet`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please state the scenario or requirement for filling the ListView.

Comment: I've a ListView which has to filled from database values,so filling the ListView using Dataset will be faster/efficient or Using Observable Collection(i.e adding values to ObservableCollection to fill the ListView)  will be faster/efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always go for ObservableCollection, I'd never use a DataSet bound directly to a control.
And if you are not changing the items in the collection, you should consider using List.

But with a little more info, maybe there would be good reason to use the dataset, but I don't think so.